# How to set globally writable permissions on SQLite WAL and SHM files?

Tags: sqlite

SQLite creates WAL and SHM files when in WAL mode. These files seem to be created with 644 permissions (r/w for creator only, and read for everyone else)

I want to use the same database file with two different OS users. When trying to write to the database with a WAL file created by another user, SQLite gives an error: `attempt to write a readonly database [8]`. This error seems to be because the WAL is not writable by the second user.

The question is therefore: how do I change the permissions on these files, given that they are created and deleted by SQLite itself so can't just be changed manually?

Answer (score 0):

Newly created files by SQLite will follow the system defaults for created files.

Ensure that the parent directory has the correct world-writable permission, and that the umask allows this. (parent dir should have 777 permissions, and umask should be 000).

All processes accessing the DB must have the correct umask. It is possible to work around this for exactly one process without the correct umask, if all the other processes run as root (and thus can access an incorrectly permissioned WAL file).

Theoretically, it should also be possible to enable WAL persistence and avoid this issue.